# Create a Graph and return it as an image on a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, chart.js, plotly

I'm trying to build a Nodejs server to generate graphs and convert them to png or jpeg file. I looked at various libraries such as Chartjs and Plotly but I can't get them to work like I want because most of these libraries are meant for frontend implementation. Ideally I would send a POST request with some data for the chart as a body and then return an image file as a download. Im trying to think of a way where I don't need to save the image on the server, just create the chart, send it to the client and destroy it from the server to avoid memory leaks.

Could somebody please point me in a direction

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a library like [chartjs-node-canvas](https://github.com/SeanSobey/ChartjsNodeCanvas) or [chartjs-node](https://github.com/vmpowerio/chartjs-node).  These solutions render charts to PNG or other image formats.

Here's what a chart render looks like in chartjs-node-canvas:

```js
const { CanvasRenderService } = require('chartjs-node-canvas');

const width = 400; //px
const height = 400; //px
const canvasRenderService = new CanvasRenderService(width, height, (ChartJS) => { });

(async () => {
    const configuration = {
        // Add your Chart.js config here
    };
    const image = await canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer(configuration);
    const dataUrl = await canvasRenderService.renderToDataURL(configuration);
    const stream = canvasRenderService.renderToStream(configuration);
})();
```

You would still need to build your own web server.  If you prefer a chart API that includes the rendering web server, you can use something like [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io/), which is an open-source project of mine that wraps chartjs-node-canvas and renders your Chart.js charts.

In that case your code might look like this:

```js
const QuickChart = require('quickchart-js');

const myChart = new QuickChart();
myChart
  .setConfig({
    type: 'bar',
    data: { labels: ['Hello world', 'Foo bar'], datasets: [{ label: 'Foo', data: [1, 2] }] },
  })
  .setWidth(800)
  .setHeight(400);

const chartImageUrl = myChart.getUrl();
// Download the url...
```